# How to use NavLinkv6 TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm using TypeScript with the new version of ReactRouter.

When I try to use the callback with the prop `className` and `style`, this returns me a `typeError`.

> Value of type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => { color: string;
> }' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number,
> string & {}>

```
<NavLink
            style={({ isActive }) => ({
              color: isActive ? "green" : "blue",
            })}
            to="/"
 >
```

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your `@types/react-router-dom` package to the latest version supporting the new typings?

Comment: The latest version on the NPM website is 5.3.2 :(

Comment: The type definition versions doesn't follow the package ones. Upgrade to `5.3.2` and you'll solve your problem. You can verify here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/92339767e14b8e26e8f46c56511e0c8e65de68c4/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts#L77.

Comment: But I'm already working with that version

Comment: According to your error message, you're not.

Comment: According to my package.json  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2"

Comment: Can you verify your version issuing: `npm list @types/react-router-dom`. It may be different from the one specified in `package.json` for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using react-router-dom 6 which ships with the type definitions.

You can add the type to the props.

Although I'm not sure why we need to. Maybe someone can expend on why.

```
${({isActive}: {isActive: Boolean;}) => (isActive ? "red" : "blue")}`}
```